# select query to return datetime from string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql query

```
 Select ISNULL([SaleDate] ,'Totals') AS [DispTotals],
case when SaleDate is null then '  ' else CONVERT(datetime, SaleDate, 103) end AS   [DayOfDateDD],
FROM ()------
```

The result of a sql query

```
DispTotals      DayOfDateDD
26/05/2013  2013-05-26 00:00:00.000
27/05/2013  2013-05-27 00:00:00.000
Totals      1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

I know the last row of SaleDate is null value.
when i change the query like:

```
Select ISNULL([SaleDate] ,'Totals') AS [DispTotals],
case when SaleDate is null then 'NULLVALUE ' else 'NONULL' end AS [DayOfDateDD],
```

The result is:

```
DispTotals      DayOfDateDD
26/05/2013  NONULL
27/05/2013  NONULL
Totals      NULLVALUE
```

I want an empty space when there is a null value(**NULLVALUE**) in SaleDate.
I am not sure how to figure this out.

Any help please.

Comment: You shouldn't use SQL queries for formatting output data

Comment: Thanks. but for the reports i use, i need to format in sql query.

Comment: I disagree Andrey, in SQL2012 they added very handy FORMAT function to aid in formatting output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CONVERT(datetime, NULLIF(SaleDate, ''), 103)
```

has helped to avoid **1900-01-01 00:00:00.000**

Comment: *‘I want an empty space when there is a null value’* – based on you answer, it appears the other way around: you want a null value when there is an empty space.

Answer (score 0):

You want to display a blank instead of NULL for a date field?  Since blank casts as 1900... default date value, you'd have to convert back to VARCHAR:

```
CAST(ISNULL(CASE WHEN SaleDate IS NULL
             THEN NULL
             ELSE CONVERT(datetime, SaleDate, 103) 
             END,''),AS VARCHAR(20))
```

If the inside CONVERT statement returns a NULL then you can get rid of the CASE statement altogether, and just keep the CAST(ISNULL( wrapper.